# Cache RDMS data in spark after creating sparkstreaming context

Tags: mysql, hadoop, caching, apache-spark, spark-streaming

We use Spark Streaming to get data from Kafka using createDirectStream.

In the same program I connect to MYSQL to get some data from the database. Now I would like to cache this result using spark.

The problem here is I have created a spark streaming context at the start , now to cache this MYSQL data I would have to convert that to a RDD that is possible only with the help of spark context, unfortunately I cannot create a spark context(since a context has already been created in terms of spark streaming).

I don't want to set `spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts = true` to allow the JVM to use more than spark context as that might cause a problem.

*Is there a way to cache this using spark or how do we convert the result of MYSQL to an RDD?*

Comment: This question is of topic as too broad to answer here. Try to look into Alluxio (ex.Tachyon)

Comment: Tachyon is there. I just wanted to know whether it is possible to create an RDD somehow here or cache it using streamingcontext(if it is not possible to create an RDD).

Comment: you can always pull data from mysql using the dataframe read api with jdbc format then you can convert it to an RDD[Row] with .rdd and use it as you wish

Comment: But doesn't creating a dataframe require a sparkcontext, which again will result in two context's.

Comment: does the data in MySQL changes during the lifetime of your streaming job? Would you like to 'pull' those changes into the streaming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go according to the description of your issue. Let's consider that you are initiating a StreamingContext as followed :

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("NetworkWordCount")
val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(1))
```

You can always fetch the SparkContext from your streaming context as followed :

```
val sc = ssc.sparkContext
```

and then do what ever it is you are trying to do. It is the associated Spark context for your streaming context, so no need to create a new Spark Context for that matter.

Comment: Forgot that streamingcontext is within sparkcontext. Thanks I will just try that and accept your answer.

Comment: your question kinda confused me as well :)

Comment: I thought that you were trying to have 2 isolated environments